# MongoDB query - Unwind with group and project and match and limit

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have below type of data:

```
    {
        "_id" : "HCCIDM1234567A",
        "RecordT" : "THISAPTC",
        "history" : [ 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-14T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-09T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : 1200,"PremChange" : 1300,"MbrRespChg" : 100,
        "NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-15T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-10T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : 16,"PremChange" : 0,"MbrRespChg" : -200,
        "NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-16T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-08T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : -16,"PremChange" : 0,
        "MbrRespChg" : -224,"NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-17T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-07T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : 0,"PremChange" : 15,
        "MbrRespChg" : -224,"NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-18T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-06T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : 0,"PremChange" : -15,
        "MbrRespChg" : -70,"NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-19T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-05T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : -10,"PremChange" : -15,
        "MbrRespChg" : -77, "NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-20T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-04T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : 0,"PremChange" : 1,
        "MbrRespChg" : 77,"NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-12T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-23T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "PremChange" : 0,"APTCChange" : 16,
        "MbrRespChg" : -200,"NPN" : "U65"
    }
]
},
{
"_id" : "HCCIDM1234567B",
"RecordT" : "THISAPTC",
"history" : [ 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-14T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-09T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : 1200,
        "PremChange" : 1300,
        "MbrRespChg" : 100,
        "NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-15T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-10T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : 16,
        "PremChange" : 0,
        "MbrRespChg" : -200,
        "NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-16T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-08T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : -16,
        "PremChange" : 0,
        "MbrRespChg" : -224,
        "NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-17T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-07T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : 0,
        "PremChange" : 15,
        "MbrRespChg" : -224,
        "NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-18T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-06T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : 0,
        "PremChange" : -15,
        "MbrRespChg" : -70,
        "NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-19T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-05T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : -10,
        "PremChange" : -15,
        "MbrRespChg" : -77,
        "NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-20T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-04T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "APTCChange" : 0,
        "PremChange" : 1,
        "MbrRespChg" : 77,
        "NPN" : "U65"
    }, 
    {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-12T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-23T11:13:14.000Z"),
        "PremChange" : 0,
        "APTCChange" : 16,
        "MbrRespChg" : -200,
        "NPN" : "U65"
    }
]
}, 
{
    "_id" : "HCCIDM1234567C",
    "RecordT" : "THISAPTC",
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-14T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-09T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "APTCChange" : 1200,
            "PremChange" : 1300,
            "MbrRespChg" : 100,
            "NPN" : "U65"
        }, 
        {
            "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-15T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-10T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "APTCChange" : 16,
            "PremChange" : 0,
            "MbrRespChg" : -200,
            "NPN" : "U65"
        }, 
        {
            "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-16T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-08T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "APTCChange" : -16,
            "PremChange" : 0,
            "MbrRespChg" : -224,
            "NPN" : "U65"
        }, 
        {
            "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-17T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-07T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "APTCChange" : 0,
            "PremChange" : 15,
            "MbrRespChg" : -224,
            "NPN" : "U65"
        }, 
        {
            "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-18T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-06T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "APTCChange" : 0,
            "PremChange" : -15,
            "MbrRespChg" : -70,
            "NPN" : "U65"
        }, 
        {
            "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-19T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-05T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "APTCChange" : -10,
            "PremChange" : -15,
            "MbrRespChg" : -77,
            "NPN" : "U65"
        }, 
        {
            "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-20T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-04T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "APTCChange" : 0,
            "PremChange" : 1,
            "MbrRespChg" : 77,
            "NPN" : "U65"
        }, 
        {
            "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-12T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-23T11:13:14.000Z"),
            "PremChange" : 0,
            "APTCChange" : 16,
            "MbrRespChg" : -200,
            "NPN" : "U65"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below conditions needs to apply:

1. startDate $gte ISODate('2018-01-15T11:13:14.000Z') & endDate $lte ISODate('2018-02-12T11:13:14.000Z')
2. need to group them based on below category

   PremChange>10- records will in one set with limit
    APTCChange>10- records will in one set with limit
    MbrRespChg>10- records will in one set with limit

Expected result:

```
    {
       id: APTCChange,
       "RecordT" : "THISAPTC",
       "hccid':'HCCIDM1234567A',
      'startDate': ISODate("2018-01-14T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-09T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "APTCChange" : 1200,
      "PremChange" : 1300,
      "MbrRespChg" : 100,
      "NPN" : "U65"
     }
     -------- 
     {
       id: APTCChange,
       "RecordT" : "THISAPTC",
       "hccid':'HCCIDM1234567A',
      'startDate': ISODate("2018-01-15T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-08T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "APTCChange" : 16,
      "PremChange" : 0,
      "MbrRespChg" : -200,
       "NPN" : "U65"
     }
     ---------
     {
       id: PremChange,
      "RecordT" : "THISAPTC",
       "hccid':'HCCIDM1234567A',
      'startDate': ISODate("2018-01-16T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-07T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "APTCChange" : 0,
      "PremChange" : 15,
      "MbrRespChg" : -224,
      "NPN" : "U65"
     } 
    -----
   {
       id: MbrRespChg,
       "RecordT" : "THISAPTC",
       "hccid':'HCCIDM1234567A',
      'startDate': ISODate("2018-01-18T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-04T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "APTCChange" : 0,
      "PremChange" : 1,
      "MbrRespChg" : 77,
      "NPN" : "U65"
     }
     ---
     {
       id: APTCChange,
       "RecordT" : "THISAPTC",
       "hccid':'HCCIDM1234567B',
      'startDate': ISODate("2018-01-14T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-09T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "APTCChange" : 1200,
      "PremChange" : 1300,
      "MbrRespChg" : 100,
      "NPN" : "U65"
     }
     -------- 
     {
       id: APTCChange,
       "RecordT" : "THISAPTC",
       "hccid':'HCCIDM1234567B',
      'startDate': ISODate("2018-01-15T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-08T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "APTCChange" : 16,
      "PremChange" : 0,
      "MbrRespChg" : -200,
       "NPN" : "U65"
     }
     ---------
     {
       id: PremChange,
      "RecordT" : "THISAPTC",
       "hccid':'HCCIDM1234567B',
      'startDate': ISODate("2018-01-16T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-07T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "APTCChange" : 0,
      "PremChange" : 15,
      "MbrRespChg" : -224,
      "NPN" : "U65"
     } 
    -----
   {
       id: MbrRespChg,
       "RecordT" : "THISAPTC",
       "hccid':'HCCIDM1234567B',
      'startDate': ISODate("2018-01-18T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-04T11:13:14.000Z"),
      "APTCChange" : 0,
      "PremChange" : 1,
      "MbrRespChg" : 77,
      "NPN" : "U65"
     }
```

please suggest me how i need to write mongodb query, i wrote a
          query using match, unwind and project but i am not getting desire 
          output.

Comment: The data you've provided is malformed and badly formatted for a question. You should be using a "pretty" format. Additionally, you haven't described the problem or shown any steps you've taken to try to solve it. We can't do anything with the small amount of information you've provided.

Comment: I’ve tried to edit your OP to help make it readable, but there’s too much code so it won’t let me edit it! Please provide what query you’ve used and what your end result you’re after is

Comment: i am sorry, i am trying to give proper data format of json but in this site, keep on giving an error to make proper code format, but i am just copying from mongo and pasted, still it is giving same error.

Comment: all possible ways i have tried to post properly and clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation. Not sure why you need grouping here.

[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter histories array to where atleast one element is in the specified date range.

[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to flatten the history array.

[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter history documents where element matches the specified date range.

[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter history documents where key values are greater than 10.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$match":{
  "history":{
    "$elemMatch":{
      "startDate":{"$gte":ISODate("2018-01-15T11:13:14.000Z")},
      "endDate":{"$lte":ISODate("2018-02-12T11:13:14.000Z")}
     }
   }
 }},
 {"$unwind":"$history"},
 {"$match":{
   "history.startDate":{"$gte":ISODate("2018-01-15T11:13:14.000Z")}, 
   "history.endDate":{"$lte":ISODate("2018-02-12T11:13:14.000Z")}
 }},
 {"$match":{
   "$or":[
     {"history.APTCChange":{"$gt":10}},
     {"history.PremChange":{"$gt":10}},
     {"history.MbrRespChg":{"$gt":10}}
    ]
 }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response, i need to group it like, {"history.APTCChange":{"$gt":10}} will be one group and {"history.PremChange":{"$gt":10}}, will be one more group and  {"history.MbrRespChg":{"$gt":10}} will be one final group

Comment: thanks for clear edit @Veeram, appreciate your help.

Comment: I am able to do that before also, but i need to group it based on greater then condition and limit those records with in the group and history would not be in sub document, now i am doing in python level convert to plan json instead sub document.

Comment: Np. Try `{
        "$facet": {
            "APTCChange": [
                 {$match:{"history.APTCChange":{"$gt":10}}}
            ],
            "PremChange": [
                {$match:{"history.APTCChange":{"$gt":10}}}
            ],
            "MbrRespChg": [
                {$match:{"history.MbrRespChg":{"$gt":10}}}
            ]
        }
    }` as last stage.

Comment: Note if you can store `"APTCChange" : 1200,"PremChange" : 1300,"MbrRespChg" : 100,` as `[Changes:{name:"APTCChange", value:1200}, {name:"PremChange", value:1300} ...]`. This will help you use $group stage using _id key as `Changes.name` to group documents.

Comment: Thanks a lot @veeram,i have modify the query which have given, now its working as expected, db.premiumChange.aggregate([
 
 {"$unwind":"$history"},
 {"$match":{
   "history.startDate":{"$gte":ISODate("2018-01-15T11:13:14.000Z")}, 
   "history.endDate":{"$lte":ISODate("2018-02-12T11:13:14.000Z")}
 }},

 { "$facet": { "APTCChange": [ {$match:{"history.APTCChange":{"$gt":10}}} ], 
 "PremChange": [ {$match:{"history.APTCChange":{"$gt":10}}} ], 
 "MbrRespChg": [ {$match:{"history.MbrRespChg":{"$gt":10}}} ] } }
])

Comment: please check once at your end also, is there any mistake in the query or any performance issues may come and how can i get the count and how can i provide the limit with in the APTCChange array and premchange and mbrrespchg

Comment: Np. Sorry, I cant comment on performance. You've to test the performance for yourself. Add `{$limit: limit value }` in each facet. What count are you looking for ?

Comment: @veeram-for count: { "$facet": { "APTCChange": [ {$match:{"history.APTCChange":{"$gt":10}}}, {$count: 'count'}], 
 "PremChange": [ {$match:{"history.APTCChange":{"$gt":10}}}, {$count: 'count'}], 
 "MbrRespChg": [ {$match:{"history.MbrRespChg":{"$gt":10}}}, {$count: 'count'}] } }
 ,  {"$unwind":"$APTCChange"},   {"$unwind":"$PremChange"}, {"$unwind":"$MbrRespChg"}, please check

Comment: @Veeram- {
    "APTCChange" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "HCCIDM1234567A","history" : {
                "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-15T11:13:14.000Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-10T11:13:14.000Z"),
                "APTCChange" : 16,
                "PremChange" : 0}
        }]
} instead can we able to get like

Comment: @veeram-{
    "APTCChange" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "HCCIDM1234567A",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-15T11:13:14.000Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-02-10T11:13:14.000Z"),
                "APTCChange" : 16,
                "PremChange" : 0
        }]
} like avoiding sub document, can we do that

Comment: Add`$project` stage as last stage to format the startDate and endDate in in each `$facets` stage. Something like `{$project:{incldue all the other fields, startDate:"$history.startDate", endDate:"$history.endDate"}}`

Comment: @Veeram-Thanks a lot :)